# Setting link within sitemap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm currently working on a project that uses a sitemap for a Telerik menu control.  I'm trying to add a new button to the menu called Reports that will open a new page/tab for users to a Report Server link.

I am able to place the button onto the page, however, nothing happens when I click it currently.  Here is the implementation of the sitemap (the node primarily, along with one that works currently).

Doesn't work at the moment

```
<siteMapNode title="Reports" nopResource="Admin.Reports" PermissionNames="ManageReports" ImageUrl="" URL="http://f7003214/Reports/SupplyCatalogTest">
      </siteMapNode>
```

Does work

```
<siteMapNode title="Dashboard" nopResource="Admin.Dashboard" controller="Home" action="Index" ImageUrl="~/Administration/Content/images/ico-dashboard.png" />
```

Also, I'm wanting my URL to open a new tab/window, not redirect the user.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind this question.  I came up with another solution.  I created a Controller and View to solve the issue.  Within the Controller, I set the links in a Model, then within the View, I redirect the user directly to the Reporting Server via Javascript in a new tab/window.